# Excel conditional formatting for entire column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formatting, conditional-formatting

I want to apply conditional formatting to entire column.

Here is my requirement:

I want to highlight a cell if it has a value (date to be specific) greater than its adjacent cell.

For e.g.: Lets say B2 has greater date than A2, then B2 should get highlighted in red. If B2 has equal value to A2 then B2 should get highlighted to green and if B2 has lesser value that A2 then B2 should get highlighted in yellow.

I want to apply this rule to entire B column like if B3 > A3 then B3 should be red. B4>A4 then B4 should be red and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have headers?

Two options really:

- Select `A2:B100` or whichever final row
- Select whole of column B

---

You need three conditional formatting rules based on formulas

For the first option these are:

- `=$B2<$A2` Apply yellow
- `=$B2=$A2` Apply green
- `=$B2>$A2` Apply red

For the second option these are:

- `=AND(ISNUMBER($B2),$B2<$A2)` Apply yellow
- `=AND(ISNUMBER($B2),$B2=$A2)` Apply green
- `=AND(ISNUMBER($B2),$B2>$A2)` Apply red

[image]